# TFS Clear Notification Job Queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, notifications, alert

Was wondering how to clear notification job queue. Seems after updating TFS from 2013 to 2017 some of email alerts got stuck for a period of time. Is it possible to just clear all of the notification queue?
Do I just need to clear tbl_JobQueue in tfs configuration DB for a 'A4804DCF-4BB6-4109-B61C-E59C2E8A9FF7' email notification JobID or is there something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you need to clear the queries from `[Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobQueue]` for the email notification JobID '`A4804DCF-4BB6-4109-B61C-E59C2E8A9FF7`'

If there are other deliveries, you can also clear the query based on the JobId accordingly:

> '`A96D6177-BEEF-477A-A2EE-2C31433214D0`', -- email, soap, etc. delivery
>
> '`A0C22F34-652E-4B9C-A06B-3F4AFE4BE458`' -- service hooks delivery
>
> See [Troubleshooting issues with Visual Studio Team Services and TFS Notifications / Alerts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rihamselim/2016/08/23/troubleshooting-issues-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-tfs-notifications-alerts/)

Besides, you can also clear the queues from collection DB `[Tfs_Collection].[dbo].[tbl_MailQueue]` if needed.