# TFS 2017 How to manually clear tbl_NotificationQueue

Tags: tfs

Without much detail on the how, we have had a rogue process cause a large amount of notification records to be triggered in TFS. Our tbl_NotificationQueue table has grown to 22million records in only 3 days, which is now causing us disk space issues. How can we either trigger the clean up job or manually clean out these records?

Answer (score 1):

Generally we don't recommend to do actions against the DB, but seems there isn't a good way to do that.

Whatever, you can delete the queues directly from the table (Backup the DB before the action in case meet unexpected problems).

e.g.

```
 DELETE FROM [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_NotificationQueue] WHERE EventDate > 2017-12-01
```

You may also need to clear the **Notification Job Queues**, reference this thread: [TFS Clear Notification Job Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409992/tfs-clear-notification-job-queue)

Comment: @Robert Have you resolved the issue? any update? BTW, you need to analysis and get the root cause to prevent gererating the records again and again.